# compile errors c++ "was not declared in this scope" "expected type specifier" etc

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

Here is a list of errors I am seeing

```
RST.hpp:23:18: error: ‘RSTNode’ has not been declared
RST.hpp:23:38: error: ‘RSTNode’ has not been declared
RST.hpp:23:45: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
RST.hpp:41:30: error: ‘RSTNode’ has not been declared
RST.hpp:41:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
RST.hpp:44:28: error: ‘RSTNode’ has not been declared
RST.hpp:44:35: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
RST.hpp: In member function ‘virtual void RST<Data>::leftRotate(int)’:
RST.hpp:25:7: error: ‘RSTNode’ was not declared in this scope
RST.hpp:25:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
RST.hpp:25:23: error: ‘dummyone’ was not declared in this scope
RST.hpp:25:34: error: ‘ptr’ was not declared in this scope
RST.hpp:26:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
RST.hpp:26:23: error: ‘dummytwo’ was not declared in this scope
RST.hpp:27:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
RST.hpp:27:23: error: ‘dummythree’ was not declared in this scope
RST.hpp: In member function ‘virtual bool RST<Data>::addToTree(int)’:
RST.hpp:46:11: error: ‘ptr’ was not declared in this scope
RST.hpp:48:13: error: ‘num’ was not declared in this scope
RST.hpp:50:11: error: ‘temp’ was not declared in this scope
RST.hpp:55:11: error: ‘temp’ was not declared in this scope
RST.hpp:63:20: error: expected type-specifier before ‘RSTNode’
RST.hpp:63:20: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘RSTNode’
RST.hpp:64:23: error: ‘temp’ was not declared in this scope
RST.hpp: In member function ‘bool RST<Data>::insert(const Data&) [with Data = countint]’:
test_RST.cpp:43:23:   instantiated from here
RST.hpp:14:7: error: no matching function for call to             RST<countint>::addToTree(BSTNode<countint>*&, NULL, const countint&)’
RST.hpp:14:7: note: candidate is:
RST.hpp:44:18: note: bool RST<Data>::addToTree(int) [with Data = countint]
RST.hpp:44:18: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
```

this is all of my code except for the tester which is fine @ this point
http://pastebin.com/3zu0hAy1

please help, I am not sure why this is happening!

NOTE: BST is a superclass of RST // BSTNode is a superclass of RSTNode

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you have not included "RSTNode.hpp" in "RST.hpp". So the 'RSTNode not declared' error message is exactly right.

The error is not what I guessed in your previous question, so you better undo that change.

Comment: thank you, so silly for me to not notice...bah
but now I have a whole slew of other errors..aggghh

Comment: Par for the course I'm afraid. Template code introduces a whole new set of error possibilities.